# ui bootstrap tpl version 2.5.0 not supporting carousel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I have struggling with following issue since 2 days. I need to implement modal popup, where I got the "Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider" error. So I upgraded the version of ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js from 0.10.0 to 2.5.0. It fixed my modal popup issue, but it ruined my carousel completely. Please help me out.
I'm using 
Angular Version - 1.5.3
ui bootstrap min. js version - 1.3.3
ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js - 2.5.0

```
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-ocLazyLoad/ocLazyLoad.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<carousel interval="myInterval">
                                <slide active="guide.active">
                                    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('{{guide.image}}');"></div>
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <h4>{{guide.type}}</h4>
                                        <h5>{{guide.time_duration}}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-caption-hover">
                                        <h4>{{guide.type}}</h4>
                                        <h5>{{guide.time_duration}}</h5>
                                        <div class="btn-row">
                                            <a ui-sref="root.guide({city_slug: '{{cityData.slug}}', guide_type_slug: '{{guide.slug}}'})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Book Now</a>  
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </slide>
                            </carousel>
```

```js
app.controller('GuideCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, WebService) {
    $scope.myInterval = 3000;
    WebService.GuideType().then(function (response) {
        if (response.success){
            $scope.guides = response.data;
            $rootScope.guidesList = $scope.guides;
        }
    });
});
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete solution which worked for my issue.
I've removed

`<script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

And downgraded uib version from 2.5.0 to 1.2.1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Also changed html in this way

```
<uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
                            <uib-slide ng-repeat="g in guide" index="$index">
                                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('{{guide.image}}');"></div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h4>{{guide.type}}</h4>
                                    <h5>{{guide.time_duration}}</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption-hover">
                                    <h4>{{guide.type}}</h4>
                                    <h5>{{guide.time_duration}}</h5>
                                    <div class="btn-row">
                                        <a ui-sref="root.guide({city_slug: '{{cityData.slug}}', guide_type_slug: '{{guide.slug}}'})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Book Now</a>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </uib-slide>
                        </uib-carousel>
```

Added this to script

```
$scope.noWrapSlides = false;
```

Comment: why did you downgrade? 2.5.0 fully supports the carousel

Comment: It was ruining my carousel css, also carousel was not working. But now another issue comes from carousel with compile error for non-assignable.
Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'active' used with directive 'uibCarousel' is non-assignable!

Answer (score 0):

You have two different versions of the same library

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Remove the first one

also, use the new prexied directive `uib-carousel`

```
<div uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
  <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It approx helped me. Thanks